# python, inheritance, super() method

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I'm new to python, I have the code below which I just can't get to work:-
This is inheritance, I have a circle base class and I inherit this within a `circle` class (just single inheritance here).

I understand the issue is within the `ToString()` function within the `circle` class, specifically the line, `text = super(Point, self).ToString() +..`
which requires at least a single argument, yet I get this:

`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'ToString'`

I know `super` has no `ToString` attribute, but the `Point` class does -

My code:

```
class Point(object):
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    # point class constructor
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print("point constructor")

    def ToString(self):
        text = "{x:" + str(self.x) + ", y:" + str(self.y) + "}\n"
        return text

class Circle(Point):
    radius = 0.0

    # circle class constructor
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        super(Point, self)              #super().__init__(x,y)
        self.radius = radius
        print("circle constructor")

    def ToString(self):
        text = super(Point, self).ToString() + "{radius = " + str(self.radius) + "}\n"
        return text


shapeOne = Point(10,10)
print( shapeOne.ToString() ) # this works fine

shapeTwo = Circle(4, 6, 12)
print( shapeTwo.ToString() ) # does not work
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in the `Circle` class instead:

```
text = super(Circle, self).ToString() + "{radius = " + str(self.radius) + "}\n"
```

`super()` will look through the base classes of the first argument to find the next `ToString()` method, and `Point` doesn't have a parent with that method.

With that change, the output is:

```
>>> print( shapeTwo.ToString() )
{x:0.0, y:0.0}
{radius = 12}
```

Note that you make the same mistake in your `__init__`; you are not calling the inherited `__init__` at all. This works:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
    super(Circle, self).__init__(x ,y)
    self.radius = radius
    print("circle constructor")
```

and then the output becomes:

```
>>> shapeTwo = Circle(4, 6, 12)
point constructor
circle constructor
>>> print( shapeTwo.ToString() )
{x:4, y:6}
{radius = 12}
```

Comment: many thanks(!) that's a step further but not the desired result, so I think I've done something else wrong here. I now get this -                                                                 point constructor
{x:10, y:10}

circle constructor
{x:0.0, y:0.0}
{radius = 12}

Comment: when my circle object was, shapeTwo = Circle(4, 6, 12)

Comment: So I should of asked, how do I pass the x,y points from Circle to Point?

Comment: OK, thanks, I now understand - so to be clear, to use the inherited initialization I have to pass the current class to super(), as well as the required arguments? as in, super(inheritedClass, self).__init__(base class arguments) ?